# Disabling Youtube autoplay when providing a URL link

Tags: url, youtube

I need to provide people with a URL link to some of my Youtube videos, but I don't want Youtube to then automatically display some random video that it thinks should be "up next". There's nothing more embarrassing than trying to show people your work and then up pops a ridiculous video that they think must be yours as well.

I've tried tacking on "&autoplay=false" and "&autoplay=0" to the end of the URL, but that doesn't work.

Anyone know what needs to be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can send people an embed link that shows the video only. I think in your case this would be fine, but for anyone that requires comments, it would be an issue. Also adding `?rel=0` will stop the end card from showing related videos from another users channel.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/OefocRFlDss?rel=0

A list of embed params can be found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's not possible, but maybe you could embed that video via API to some server you own,  and disable the suggestions.

Check this documentation for disabling, controls and siggestions.

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay
- Or this: http://illuminea.com/remove-related-videos-from-end-of-embedded-youtube-video/

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This feature does not seem to be customizable from the url; it's more of a user setting. You can find [here](https://www.404techsupport.com/2014/10/how-disable-youtubes-new-autoplay-suggested-videos/) some details about how to turn it off for yourself but you cannot control the way it will behave for others.

Also, I'm not sure if this question qualifies as a programming one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution -- add `?t=9999999&rel=0` to the URL, which should jump to the end of the video and stop there. (Yeah, not great, but it seems to be the best bad option available.)

Details:

- The `t=` parameter tells it to jump to a time index, in seconds. In this case, the intent is to use a(n absurdly) large value to effectively jump to the end of the video.
- The `rel=0` parameter tells it not to jump to the next related video -- effectively, stop and wait.

While you won't get the video queued up at the beginning, you will at least get it positioned to easily restart.